# Ubuntu One CORS support

Tags: ubuntu-one, development, application-development, ubuntu-one-api

I am in the process of trying to build a webapp that integrates with Ubuntu One. It would seem that I am unable to authorize a user as per https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/limited_tokens/cloud/ using Javascript due to a lack of CORS http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ implementation which allows cross domain Javascript loading.

Will there be any future plans to support a more webapp friendly approach to authentication?

Answer (score 1):

CORS headers are something that I've been thinking about adding to the Ubuntu One APIs. Can you talk a little more about what you're planning to build? I'm trying to get a picture of which APIs it would be useful to enable. Do please drop me an email if you'd rather chat that way, or find me on IRC (freenode, as "aquarius").

Comment: I want an app to access and edit my One Notes but through a very intuitive interface. The simplicity of Tomboy on the desktop could work really well on touch devices if the interface is reworked. I'm thinking slates here, Playbook, iPad etc. I think with this type of app allowing a webapp could reach more touch devices than a native app can at a fraction of the effort. I do understand that it isn't recommended to access notes through Ubuntu One's API but rather Tomboy  due to the sync process but building an app for Ubuntu One leaves the door open to more features in the future.

Comment: A lot more vendors are supporting native web apps and by this I mean building an HTML5 app that is packaged and delivered as a native app. Blackberry Webworks is a great example. Enabling CORS would most definitely create more possibility to integrate with Ubuntu One.

Comment: Yep, CORS-enabling the notes API would be nice, but that wouldn't immediately help; you'd still need an oauth token to actually access the API. This is all doable, though, which is why I'm trying to get a handle on which direction it'd be best to go here.